# Lotusscript MIME Email

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I modified a code that I found to send MIME HTML mails with attachments.
It works when the mail is open in gmail, but in Apple Mail or Lotus Notes there isn't any attachment in the body.
The plaintext part does not arrive either, but what interests me are the attachments.

Here is my code:

```
    Set MailDoc     = New NotesDocument( mailbox )
    session.convertMIME = False 
    Dim body As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim mimeHeader As NotesMIMEHeader
    Dim mimeEntity As NotesMIMEEntity
    Dim stream As NotesStream
```

Set body = mailDoc.CreateMIMEEntity

```
    Set mimeHeader = body.CreateHeader({MIME-Version})
    Call mimeHeader.SetHeaderVal("1.0")
    Set mimeHeader = body.CreateHeader("Content-Type")
    Call mimeHeader.SetHeaderValAndParams({multipart/alternative;boundary="=NextPart_="})

    ' create another MIME part for the attachment. (repeat as needed)
    If (docEval.HasItem("$File")) Then
        Dim AttachmentsField As NotesRichTextItem
        Set AttachmentsField = docEval.GetFirstItem( "fc_adjunto" )
        If IsArray(AttachmentsField.EmbeddedObjects) Then ' Isarray validates for attachments ignoring embedded text
            ForAll att In AttachmentsField.EmbeddedObjects
                If att.Type = EMBED_ATTACHMENT Then
                    Call errorLog.LogAction("Inicio attch: " + att.Name())
                    Set mimeEntity = body.CreateChildEntity( )
                    Set mimeHeader = mimeEntity.CreateHeader("Content-Disposition")
                    aliasFilename = CStr(att.Name())
                    Call mimeHeader.SetHeaderValAndParams(|attachment; filename=| & aliasFilename)
                    Set stream = session.CreateStream
                    attachFilename = AttachToFile(session, docEval, CStr(att.Name()))  'Call o.ExtractFile(Attachfoldername & "\" & o.Name())
                    Call errorLog.LogAction("Inicio attch name: " + attachFilename)
                    stream.Open attachFileName, "binary"
                    Call mimeEntity.SetContentFromBytes(stream, "application/octet-stream", ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
                    mimeEntity.EncodeContent(ENC_BASE64)
                    Kill attachFilename
                End If
            End ForAll
        End If
    End If  

    'Send the plain text part first (this never work for me!!)
    Set mimeEntity = body.createChildEntity()
    Set stream = session.createStream()
    Call WritePlainText(stream)
    Call mimeEntity.setContentFromText(stream, {text/plain;charset="iso-8859-1"}, ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT)

    'Send the HTML part.
    Call stream.Truncate()

    'Send the HTML part.
    Set mimeEntity = body.createChildEntity()
    Call WriteHTML(stream, elHtml)
    Call mimeEntity.setContentFromText(stream, {text/html;charset="iso-8859-1"},ENC_IDENTITY_8BIT)
    'Close the stream and Send it
    Call stream.Truncate()
    Call stream.Close()

    Call maildoc.Closemimeentities(True)

    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("EncryptOnSend"   , True )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("PostedDate"      , Now )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("From"            , Remitente )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("SendFrom"        , Remitente )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue("Principal"       , Remitente )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue( "SendTo"         , sendTo )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue( "CopyTo"         , copyTo )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue( "BlindCopyTo"    , bccTo )
    Call MailDoc.ReplaceItemValue( "Subject"        , Subject )
    Call MailDoc.save( True , False ) 'Send it 
    session.convertMIME = True
```

Any idea what could I miss?
Thanks

Comment: What do the finished mime headers look like?  Boundary, Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, end boundary, etc..  What does it look like in Notes or Apple Mail?

Comment: Try replacing "application/octet-stream" with "binary",

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are using only a multipart/alternative section. I don't see a multipart/mixed section. I believe that you need to have a nested structure like this:

```
 multipart/mixed
   application/octet-stream
   application/octet-stream (etc...)
   multipart/alternative
     text/plain
     text/HTML
```

Send yourself a hand-crafted email that looks the way that you want it to, and verify the MIME headers in the received message to be sure I've got this right ('View - Show - Page Source' in the Notes client or 'Show Original' in gmail), but I'm looking at several messages with attachments in my own inbox, and they've all got this structure.

Comment: I've changed the line
Call mimeHeader.SetHeaderValAndParams({multipart/alternative;boundary="=NextPart_="})
to:
Call mimeHeader.SetHeaderValAndParams({multipart/ **mixed**;boundary="=NextPart_="})

And send the plain text and the HTML, now I go for the attachment order.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The order I used was:

multipart/mixed
   multipart/alternative
     text/plain
     text/HTML
     application/octet-stream
     application/octet-stream (etc...)
Thanks @Richard

First I've changed

```
SetHeaderValAndParams({multipart/alternative;boundary="=NextPart_="})
```

To:

```
SetHeaderValAndParams({multipart/mixed;boundary="=NextPart_="})
```

Then the plain text:

```
setContentFromText(stream, {text/plain}, ENC_NONE)
```

Then the html:

```
setContentFromText(stream, {text/html;charset="iso-8859-1"}, ENC_NONE)
```

Finally:
Repeat as needed... (attachments)

```
stream.Open attachFileName, "binary" (attachFileName full path)
mc.SetContentFromBytes(stream, "application/octet-stream", ENC_IDENTITY_BINARY)
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO far better code you can find at: http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/BLOG-20091022-0419

Comment: I started with this code and never send the plain text. I used the attach comments but didn't work

Comment: My apologies. I used this code originally, but while inspecting my version again I see that I have modified quite a lot actually. If you're interested I can share it, but I just don't want to upset Jake, for the code is and isn't mine...

Comment: Don't worry, I've the code working. If you want to send your version for me its ok we can share our codes...
Thank you

Comment: A page I created the other day: http://www.bosman.fr/downloads.php